# Help me understand how we define closed sets in real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I'm currently reading the second version of *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott and on page $90$ theorem $3.2.8.$ states that "A set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed if and only if every Cauchy sequence contained in $F$ has a limit that is also an element of $F$". According to definition $3.2.7.$ on the same page "A set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed if it contains its limit points".

The proof was left as an exercise. I think I pretty much proved it but I need help understanding some of the logic involved here.

If $F$ only contains a single point then there are no sequences in $F$ that do not contain their limit so there are no limit points. Is $F$ still closed? I assume that some sort of logical mambo jambo can be applied here to show that this is the case. To say that $F$ contains all its $0$ limit points does not sit very well with me since we're treating "nothing" as a "something". We're essentially saying that $F$ contains this "nothing". It makes no sense to me. Personally I decided to just embellish the definition with "If $F$ only contains one point then it is closed, otherwise blablabla...". Is this equivalent to the previous definition?

Comment: So what if it $F$ has two points?  Are you going to further embellish your definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct when you say that a singleton set does not contain any limit points.

However, think of the proposition in the following fashion : $F$ is closed, if the set of limit points of $F$ is a subset of $F$.

Then, the set of limit points of a singleton set, is  the *empty set*, and is therefore contained in $F$. This notion clarifies the doubt of how $F$ can contain *nothing*, to a better notion of set containment.

Comment: So... what's the limit of the sequence $0,0,0,0,\ldots$ and is it an element of $\{0\}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point according to this article, we have that a limit point  $x$ of $\{0,0,0,...\}$ must satisfy : every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $S$, *other than $x$*. I know, there is a huge confusion on this : sometimes we do include limits of  constant sequences as limit points, sometimes we prefer not to. On the other hand, a *cluster point* (how many of these?)  is point $x$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $S$, therefore $0$  qualifies as a cluster point and not a limit point of $F$.

Comment: The *limit* of the sequence $0,0,0,...$ is $0$, by the epsilon-delta definition of convergence on the real line. It is an element of $\{0\}$. Therefore $0$ is *the limit*, but *not a limit point*, of the constant zero sequence.

Comment: @David You are welcome. I would like to know if Abbot also has these "cluster-point", "accumulation point", "limit point',"isolated point", "discrete point" definitions. Lastly, I would like you to read the answer below : I have upvoted it, and it gives far more information than I can provide.

Comment: Abbott claims that "Limit points are also often referred to as "cluster points" or "accumulation points"". He also says that "A point $a \in A$ is an isolated point of $A$ if it is not a limit point of $A$". There is no mention of a discrete point (thus far at least).

Comment: Funny. I couldn't find the term "limit point" in Folland's Real Analysis, or in Royden and Fizpatrick, or in Engelking, or in Hatcher. I did find it in Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds. And indeed you're right. But then again, nobody claims that a set is closed iff it contains all of its limit points. So it seems that I'm not the only one confused by this terminology. :)

Comment: So this is not a generally accepted definition of a closed set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila . There seems to  different usages by different authors, of limit-point, cluster- point,and accumulation-point .  Engelking seems to avoid this difficulty by not using  any of them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are correct, it is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a constant sequence is a Cauchy sequence. The point is that a closed set will have two type of Cauchy sequences:

1. Those that converge to a limit point of the set,
2. and those which are converge to an isolated point of the set (these will be eventually constant sequences).

So $\{0\}$ is a closed set, because the only Cauchy sequence is converging to $0$, and that's fine.

---

What this is telling us is that there are two type of points in a closed set: limit points, and isolated points. And Cauchy sequences can converge to either one, only that in the latter case the sequence has to be eventually finite.

As for your embellishment, not that there is no actual difference between a singleton and a finite set. Or $\Bbb Z$, or any closed and discrete set (i.e. a closed set of isolated points). It is a good thing to try and play with definition in order to understand them, but it's important to remember a few test cases and not just the basic one (the classic ones would be: empty, singleton, finite, discrete, dense, open, closed, and arbitrary), so before you come up with revised definitions, it is often a good idea to try a few cases and not just singletons.